# Using micro USB port as audio output

Tags: 7.0-nougat

So, the audio output jack of my Samsung Note 5 just broke and it costs too much to get it fixed locally.

Would I be able to use the micro USB port as a replacement for my audio jack assuming I had a micro USB to AUX adaptor?

Phone Model SM-N9208
Android Ver. 7.0

Comment: B;uetooth might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [this XDA post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/note5/help/usb-audio-note-5-t3196346),

> Clearly the Note 5 supports USB audio, but it appears to not work properly.

So you can be sure it is, but also you should be aware of potential incompatibilities with your USB audio peripherals.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://www.lifewire.com/usb-to-aux-cable-in-car-audio-3986249)

This is true, in most cases, if you plug a USB to aux cable into your phone and connect it to your head unit. Some phones and MP3 players are designed to output audio signals via USB connection, like the original HTC Dream that used a single micro-USB connector for both power and audio output, but most phones and MP3 players come with a standard 3.5mm or 2.5mm TRRS headphone jack for a reason.

Many phones and MP3 players aren’t specifically designed to output sound via their USB connection. The USB connection is capable of transferring digital data back and forth, and can likely also be used to charge the device, but it usually won’t be designed to output an audio signal.

The only case where you would want, or need, to output audio from a phone’s USB connection to an aux input in your head unit is if the phone didn’t also include a headphone jack. Some phones, like the original G1/HTC Dream, omitted a headphone jack in favor of the ability to output sound via the USB connection.

Can't guarantee you for your specific device but you should try this product. Its easily available in local stores and online shopping sites too.